# how to compare two rows in different table and return miss- match column from both the table

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables; 1st table containing original values and 2nd table contains modified values.  Modification might happen only in few columns.

Query output should contain only columns (fields) where change has occurred. From User Interface I will be passing only 1 Plot code (PK) at a time.

**Table 1**

```
Plot code|  address|  Owner Name| Date of pass| Status
==========================================================
         |         |            |             |
1        |  aaa    |  Abcd      | 12/02/2016  | Pending
```

**Table 2**

```
 Plot code  |   address|  Owner Name| Date of pass| Status
  =========================================================
             |         |            |             |
    1        |  aaa    |  efgh      | 12/02/2016  | Allotted
```

**Output**

```
Ori_OwnerName |Ori_Status|  Mod_ OwnerName| Mod_Status
===========================================================
Abcd          |Pending   |efgh            |  Allotted
```

Comment: "*Query output should contain only columns where change has occurred*" - this is not possible because a query needs to return the same number of columns for each row. What if two different rows differ in different columns?

Comment: Ya it may happen. At a time i should be able to parse same row in 2 table. Modification can happen in any column, In output it should reflect only those columns.

Comment: Again: it is not possible to return a result that has different columns in different rows.

Comment: I am new to SQL. Pls suggest me the way I should proceed.

Comment: 2 tables contains same columns (Schema structure). 1 table contains original values and other contains modified one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get that information as a different columns as this is impossible with SQL: every row must have the same number of columns.

You can do this however using the [`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) extension (which must be [installed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html) before you can use it):

```
select t1.plot_code, 
       hstore(t1) - hstore(t2) as original,
       hstore(t2) - hstore(t1) as changed
from t1
  join t2 on t1.plot_code = t2.plot_code
where t1 is distinct from t2;
```

The column `original` contains the modified columns and their original values. The column  `changed` contains the modified columns and their new values.

For your example this would return:

```
plot_code | original                                  | changed                                    
----------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------
        1 | "owner_name"=>"Abcd", "status"=>"Pending" | "owner_name"=>"efgh", "status"=>"Allotted"
```